# How does def d = (x: int) => f(x) get used?

Tags: scala

Let's say:

```
def f(i: Int) : String = i.toString
def d = (x: int) => f(x)
```

How does `d` get used when it doesn't take any parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, `d` returns a function that takes an `Int` and returns a `String`, so the signature of `d` is

```
def d: Int => String
```

It does not really matter whether `d` is actually implemented as `def` or `val` since it does not take parameters and deterministically returns `x => f(x)`.

So everytime you call `d`, you get back the function `x => f(x)`, which you can call like any other function that takes an `Int`, so:

```
println(d)     // prints <function1>
println(d(10)) // prints 10
println(d(5))  // prints 5
```

Functions as value can be useful, for example, if you want to pass them as a parameter to a different function. There are plenty of functions in the Scala standard library that take functions as parameter, for example

```
def isEvenNumber: Int => Boolean = i => i % 2 == 0
println(List(1, 2, 4).filter(isEvenNumber))  // prints List(2, 4)
```

Note, that in your specific case, `d` is really just an alias for the partially applied function `f _`.

Answer (score 1):

But, it does take parameters:

```
scala> def f(i: Int) : String = i.toString
f: (i: Int)String

scala> def d = (x: Int) => f(x)
d: Int => String
```

So, `d` is really a function taking an `Int` and returning a `String`....which is kind of pointless in this instance as it is doing the same thing as the original function.  This type of operation is often more useful as a means of wrapping a function and doing some other transformation using that wrapped function